# Security exception when launching bluetooth settings with adb command

Tags: android, bluetooth, adb

I am running below adb command from terminal in Mac
**adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.bluetooth.BluetoothSettings**

but this throws security exception. Logs are:
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.BluetoothSettings } from null (pid=21715, uid=2000) requires android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN

Device used is Galaxy S9 v8.0

Comment: Check **Basic operations with Android Settings**: [Helpful ADB commands](https://mmbs.github.io/tools/adb/2016/06/22/helpful-adb-commands/) and **pm** tool

Comment: I tried this adb shell am start -a android.settings.BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS but still same issue

Comment: Please read the part involving **pm grant** command to grant a permission

Comment: Also, depending on the phone model, you may need to **Allow granting permissions** in  _**Developer Options > USB debugging**_

Comment: Can you send me command to grant permission

Comment: Also, it is occurring on some of the Android devices. Can you please help?